# Concatenating strings in PostgreSQL result

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-concatenation

I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM users WHERE ...
```

and I would like to display the results like that:

```
user=12355
user=78949
user=9898
user=489891
```

Basically with "user=" prepended. Is it possible to do this with PostgreSQL? I've tried with `STRING_AGG('user=', DISTINCT(id))` but got an error on `DISTINCT(id)`. Any idea?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want one line per id or all rows concatenated with line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `||` for string concatenation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT('user=' || id) 
FROM users 
WHERE ...
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/39727/1)

This might be useful as well:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a plain `GROUP BY` for this.

```
SELECT format('user=%s',id)
FROM users
GROUP BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/39727/3

This will be considerably more efficient than using `DISTINCT` on the string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason you got an error message from [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is because you forgot the **second parameter** which is required. This very simple query would just work:

```
SELECT string_agg('user=' || id, E'\n')
FROM   users 
WHERE  ...
```

`E'\n'` .. newline character

Produces ***one row*** with the exactly the string you have in your question.
You do not need either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` unless you have duplicates in `id` - in which case you'd need a subquery:

```
SELECT string_agg('user=' || id, E'\n')
FROM  (SELECT id FROM users GROUP BY id) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply 
Select concat('user=',id) from users